How to use the ROS2 Nav2 library without lidar and camera
I'm new to ROS and I'm working on a project using ROS2 Humble. I want to navigate a robot straight using GPS and IMU sensors. I'm considering using ROS2's Nav2 library for this purpose, but I'm encountering a "No map received" warning when I try to use it without Lidar. Is it possible to navigate the robot using only GPS and IMU without Lidar or camera in Nav2? If so, could you provide step-by-step guidance on how to achieve this?
my_image
There are robots that navigate with gps, but they all have lidar, I do not want to use lidar or camera in my own project.

Your screenshot is rviz where you're specifically telling it to look for a map; if you don't have one, simply ignore or remove it. You can/should simply use an ekf node as detailed in the docs.
